# Trying to deploy an Entity Framework MVC3 application to specialist ASP.NET shared host, getting strange error?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-5

I have a 2 project MVC3 .NET 4, EF5 Web Application which I have just tried to "One-Click" Publish to my DiscountASP account which has a MS SQL Server 2008 instance installed.

The error I am getting is :

```
Schema specified is not valid. Errors:

OrdersDB.csdl(2,9) : warning 0005: Could not find schema information for the attribute          
'Namespace'.

OrdersDB.csdl(2,38) : warning 0005: Could not find schema information for the attribute 'Alias'.

OrdersDB.csdl(2,288) : error 0005: The 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/02/edm
/annotation:UseStrongSpatialTypes' attribute is not declared.

OrdersDB.csdl(2,2) : error 0010: The element Schema in namespace http://schemas.microsoft.com   
/ado/2009/11/edm was unexpected for the root element. The expected Schema in one of the 
following namespaces: http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2006/04/edm, http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/05/edm, http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2008/09/edm.
```

Any ideas please?

I just publish the web project, not the DB Project which contains the POCOs. I do not believe I need to do this as the DLL is pulled into the Web Project.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorted this, by downgrading to EF4.1

Basically EF5 will not work on W2K8 unless it has .NET4.5 which my host did not have. My dev server was compiling to .NET4 using the EF DLL, but perhaps I have .NET4.5 on my dev server, so it was working because of this. I did notice that the EF5 DLLs were marked up as DLL.45 under properties.

Hope this helps someone.